# Copy a variation Regular Price from an old variation and add it to all other new variations that are in the same product

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, hook-woocommerce

We have more than 6,000 products in WooCommerce and WordPress. We deleted some size attributes like Size 1, Size 2, and Size 3  and added other attributes like Size 4.

-The old attribute variations are now empty because we deleted their attributes but still have prices.
-The new variations are created by the bulk edit plugin PW Bulk Edit but have no prices on them.

Is there a way to copy the price from the old size variation (size 1/size 2/size 3)if any one exist to the new variation Size 4 and Size 5

--If they all exist copy from size1/ if Size 2 and 3 exist copy from size 2 / if only size 3 exist copy from size 3

Example of MySQL table wp_postmeta:

```
meta_id    post_id    meta_key             meta_value
1055        1000          _regular_price    100
1056        1001          _regular_price    100
1057        1002          _regular_price    100
```

Example of MySQL table wp_posts:

```
meta_id     ID            post_parent       
1055        1001          5000                   
1056        1002          5000                   
1057        1003          5000  
1058        1004          5000
1058        1005          5000              
    

Insert row in wp_postmeta table for each post_id the row will be:
post_id = ID of the variation in wp_posts table
meta_key=_regular_price  
meta_value = ( _regular_price   of size-1 or size-2 or size-3)
```

Expected result is to create a row in wp_postmeta table for the new variation like below

```
meta_id     post_id        meta_key         meta_value
1055        1001          _regular_price    100
1056        1002          _regular_price    100
1057        1003          _regular_price    100

1057        1004          _regular_price    100
1057        1005          _regular_price    100
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have access to wp-cli? If so you could do this with a script, looping over your products and using `get_post_meta` and `update_post_meta`.